# Google Play Store App not compatible Restriction Numbers

Tags: android, google-play, restriction

Google Playstore checks something in device and then it will give some error if this checking fails.

For example if any application is not available in any country it will give restriction = 2

> 

```
D/Finsky  ( 1043): [1] LibraryUtils.isAvailable: com.pccw.nowplayer not available [restriction=2].
D/Finsky  ( 1043): [1] LibraryUtils.isAvailable: com.pccw.nowplayer not available [restriction=2].
D/Finsky  ( 1043): [1] DocUtils.getAvailabilityRestrictionResourceId: Item is not available. Reason: 2
D/Finsky  ( 1043): [1] DetailsDataBasedFragment.rebindViews: Page [class=DetailsFragment] loaded in [16635 ms] (hasDetailsDataLoaded? false)
D/Finsky  ( 1043): [1] LibraryUtils.isAvailable: com.pccw.nowplayer not available [restriction=2].
D/Finsky  ( 1043): [1] LibraryUtils.isAvailable: com.pccw.nowplayer not available [restriction=2].
D/Finsky  ( 1043): [1] DocUtils.getAvailabilityRestrictionResourceId: Item is not available. Reason: 2
D/Finsky  ( 1043): [1] DetailsDataBasedFragment.rebindViews: Page [class=DetailsFragment] loaded in [16679 ms] (hasDetailsDataLoaded? true)
D/Finsky  ( 1043): [1] SelfUpdateScheduler.checkForSelfUpdate: Skipping DFE self-update. Local Version [80230011] >= Server Version [-1]
```

so can any one tell about restriction = 9 because i am getting it in Real Player.

Thanks.

Comment: Refer to below link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31920605/unable-to-install-some-apps-from-google-play-on-customized-aosp-item-is-not-ava

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer of this question it was due to bluetooth is not in my device.

Comment: Is there a place to see a list for all restrictions?

Answer (score 0):

switch (restriction) {
case 2:
resourceId = R.string.availability_restriction_country;
break;

Comment: availability_restriction_country

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).